# Spacy Verb highlight?

Tags: nlp, spacy

Just like spacy displacy renders entity highlights in html.

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc1 = nlp(u'This is a google sentence.')
doc2 = nlp(u'This is another sentence.')
html = displacy.render([doc1, doc2], style='ent', page=True)
```

How to highlight all verbs in a given text.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import spacy,en_core_web_sm
import textacy
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
sentence = 'The cat jumped quickly over the wall.'
doc = textacy.Doc(sentence, lang='en_core_web_sm')
for token in doc:
    if (token.pos_ == 'VERB'):
        print(token.text)
```

Here output **Jumped** is to be highlighted in green color! How?

Something similar to this

http://www.expresso-app.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use displacy ent interface to highlight custom entities by setting `manual=True` on either `render()` or `serve()`.
Here is a simple example:

```
sentence = [{'text': 'The cat jumped quickly over the wall.',
    'ents': [{'start': 8, 'end':14, 'label': 'VERB'}],
    'title': None}]

displacy.render(sentence, style='ent', manual=True)
```

[image]

Additionally, to obtain data in required format, you could do a dependency parsing and use [PhraseMatcher](https://spacy.io/api/phrasematcher) over it to get `start` and `end` values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the displacy's render or serve method with the parameters `style='ent'` and `manual=True` to highlight custom entities.

```
from spacy import displacy
import re
```

```
text = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
match_phrases = ['brown fox','lazy dog']
matches = []

for match_phrase in match_phrases:
    for item in re.finditer(match_phrase,text):
        match = {}
        match['start'], match['end'] = item.span() 
        match['label'] = '\u2713' # The tag/label that you would like to display
        matches.append(match)
        
sentence = [{
    'text': text,
    'ents': matches
}]

displacy.render(sentence, style='ent', manual=True)
```